# how to make a cordova android plugin using external non-builded lib (OpenCV)

Tags: android, cordova, opencv

I'm trying to create a cordova plugin to use OpenCV on android and iOS.
I am for the moment at the android part.

I downloaded the [OpenCV android package](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/3.1.0/OpenCV-3.1.0-android-sdk.zip/download), and create a test application with android. That work, so I just need to put that in the plugin.
But I have absolutly no idea about how to import the OpenCV library in the plugin.

Someone know how to do that ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you written a cordova plugin in the past?  If not, this is probably not the easiest place to start (if you haven't start with the [plugin guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html) from the Cordova team.).

Including JNI (native code) in Android in Cordova plugins is a bit of black art, but you are lucky that someone has gone there before (and abandoned) a 
[Cordova OpenCV plugin for Android](https://github.com/mWater/OpenCVActivityPlugin).  Study that, and then for iOS it is a lot easier, since you can CocoaPods or just include the library and don't have to worry about C/Java bridge.  If all of this is making your head hurt and you have no idea what JNI is then you might want to farm out the writing of this kind of plugin to someone else.

**EDIT**

I was going to add this in a comment but it was too long:

An apk is a complete App and not a Library.you need to include the various .so files (shared objects) for openCV.  If you want to learn how to link a C++ file into an Android app (first step of creating a Cordova Plugin with JNI check out this [tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-c-and-c-code-in-an-android-app-with-the-ndk/). However, since half the work has already been done for you, what I would do is just download the OpenCV Plugin into a directory and then

cordova plugin install

and fix what you need (if you get everything working, think about forking the original project and contribute back to the community :) ).

As stated the plugin for iOS will be similar to other IOS plugins, maybe look at the [cordova-cocoapods project](https://github.com/xdissent/cocoapods-cordova), the other [cordova-cocoapods project](https://github.com/mkcode/cocoapod-to-cordova) and the [OpenCV CocoaPod](https://cocoapods.org/pods/OpenCV).

Comment: I never make a real crodova plugin in the past, only some test plugin.

I saw the OpenCV plugin you link, but I was thinking that maybe I could importe the OpenCV library without the jni part. Obviously I was wrong, and it was stupide tp think it.

I have, for the moment, no Idea of how to make a JNI, but I don't surrend that easily. Thanks for your help.

Comment: OpenCV has an "apk" part where their are .apk file. I think it's the compressed version of the sdk part. Is their a way to import only the apk, or need I to do a jni part in all case ?

Comment: @AskamEyra I've answered your comment in the edit above.

Comment: With a lot of try, I think I finally make it. It was not so hard in fact, cause OpenCV give the .so file and all the jni part.
Il will contribute back to the community soon
Thanks for your help !